# IIS 8.5 Silent client certificate requests

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a request from my client that goes something like this:

This is a public website with *some* information for employees from the agency. My client wants to have a popup on the front page that only shows up for employees.

The agency uses CAC cards to authenticate, these cards have several certs on them. On internal sites this is pretty straight forward set up IIS accordingly and then compare against AD.

However since this is an external site, so I don't want to authenticate per se. I want IIS to check silently for the existence of the CAC/certs if they're there then run the popup logic, if not ignore it. The second part is all coding but I need to know if IIS can silently attempt to look for the CAC/Certs

My original idea was to compare the request IP against our internal IP Ranges, but my servers are behind a load balancer and by the time it gets to my servers the request would have the load balancer IP and every request would be in range.

It's a complex situation and all the digging I've done so far says it can't be done, but I wanted to ask

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't something you will be able to configure IIS to handle.  You have to code the website to offer the ability to authenticate using a SmartCard.  **IIS will be unable to determine what devices are connected to the client.**  Example of the website offering both a username and password authentication and SmartCard authentication is [here](https://mypay.dfas.mil/#/)

Answer (score 1):

A web server cannot "look" into clients' smartcards – that's *entirely* done by the web browser. About the only way IIS can influence this is by sending a list of "acceptable" certificate issuer DNs (and I think this is no longer possible in TLSv1.3 either). But if the browser thinks it needs to show a certificate list, then it *will* show a certificate list.

Most websites, even those using CAC or other client-certificate authentication, have a dedicated login URL which requires certificate auth, but the rest of the system doesn't. Instead the "logged in" state is carried through traditional cookies/sessions. This allows the system to offer several different authentication methods. (I don't know if IIS supports per-URL certificate auth; you might have to use a separate subdomain for the "login" page.)

One example is the "sign in" page at `https://account.cern.ch/account/`, which actually seems to handle everything through Microsoft ADFS.

Alternatively, you could host the entire webapp on two different subdomains: one for public access, another requiring authentication. (`https://public.cyber.mil/` is one example I've seen recently.)